Cannot authenticate to MSSQL database using AD credentials via jdbc driver
We use mssql-jdbc-12.6.4 in Logstash to connect to MSSQL database, but we are facing authentication problem: Login failed for user 'domian\username'.
Here is the traceback:

Configuration with jdbc connection string:
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/app/logstash/utils/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-12.6.4.jre11.jar"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://***:1433;databaseName=***;user=***\***;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30;"
        jdbc_user => "***"
        jdbc_password => "***"
        statement => "SELECT 1"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
    }
}

We specify username in format <domain>\<username>.
We tried to connect to DB using sqlcmd util with the same parameters and authentication was successful:
sqlcmd -C -S "***:1433" -d "***" -U "***\***" -Q "SELECT 1"

Password: 

------------
           1
(1 row affected)

Do you have any idea why authentication fails in case of using driver?

"We specify username in format <domain>\<username>." You can't do that (there are countless other posts explaining this). It's SQL Authentication, or Trusted Connection; not a mix of both. If you need to connect with a domain user, you need to run the application as that user or use impersonation.

You have to use NTLM if you're connecting with specific domain user other than yourself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 or if you just wanna use windows auth of current user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver16 (needs specific dll to be on the path)

Thank you for information. When I set integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NTLM;domain=<our domain> and remove domain part from username the log messages about failed login is gone, but then nothing happens for a long time (sql query schedule is "every minute"). Last message in logstash pipeline log is about pipeline is initialized and started.

After long time I saw log message: "Connection reset by peer", but port 1433 is available from logstash host.

Are you on windows? Try to remove logstash from the equation and create a simple java program which connects to sql server. Btw, you don't need to specify port number if it's 1433. Is your server name something like: SERVER\Instance ?

I'm on linux. We access server using its IP address (like jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.0.1:1443;...).

Seems like there's a typo somewhere in your program or in the comments, since 1443 (probably incorrect port) is not the same 1433 (correct default port).

Yeah, there was a typo in the comment above, but configuration is valid (uses 1433). I wrote some java code fragment to test jdbc driver directly. Tried with enabled integrated security and different types of authenticationScheme: NTLM and JavaKerberos. Domain controller port 88 (used for Kerberos) is reachable and I have TGT in klist but I still see behavior of long hanging and "Connection reset by peer" eventually.
